# Map getting modified unnecessarily in a for loop

Tags: apex, map

```java
for(AggregateResult sg : siteGeoIds){
    if(conNumber == String.valueOf(sg.get('VNContractNumber__c'))){
        for(Group gr : groupsToBeAdded){
            if(gr.Name.contains(String.valueOf(sg.get('SiteGeoId__c')))){
                groupIdset.add(gr.id);
            }
        }

        contractsWithGroups.put(conNumber,groupIdset);
    }else {
        conNumber = String.valueOf(sg.get('VNContractNumber__c'));
        groupIdset.clear();
        for(Group gr : groupsToBeAdded){
            if(gr.Name.contains(String.valueOf(sg.get('SiteGeoId__c')))){
                groupIdset.add(gr.id);
            }
        }

        contractsWithGroups.put(conNumber,groupIdset);
    }
}
```

In the above code, the map `contractsWithGroups` is getting cleared and modified in else block for all the keys even though another unique key with values are given.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Please use only relevant tags. This has nothing to do with triggers, Lightning, or the Salesforce One app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
contractsWithGroups.put(conNumber,groupIdset);
```

you are adding a *reference* to the collection `groupIdset` to the `Map`, not a copy of it.

This means that later loop iterations mutate the collection you've already added to the `Map` under a different `conNumber`, and when you call `clear()` on that `Set`, you're actually clearing the *one and only one `Set` that is stored under all of the `Map` keys*.

You need to be creating a new `Set` instance for each key, e.g.,

```
if (!contractsWithGroups.containsKey(someKey)) {
    contractsWithGroups.put(someKey, new Set<SomeType>());
}

thisSet = contractsWithGroups.get(someKey);
```

And then add all relevant values to `thisSet`.

Comment: Thank you @David Reed for the explanation. I understood why the Map is getting mutated for other keys. But creating a new set won't solve the problem, as I put the values in the Map after the set is added with values in the previous for loop which is used for groups.